# Flask + SQLAlchemy: Class not Iterable

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having a problem when trying to render a SQLAlchemy query into a template, the error I get is:

```
TypeError: 'Users' object is not iterable
```

The DB is a sqlite
I have been following the "Discover Real Python" tutorial on youtube and it has been a big help. The only things i have changed is in the tutorial he uses "BlogPosts", and I use "Users"

I am trying to understand how he got users to iterate in his version of the code in the template.

My `Models.py` file is this:

```
from app import db

class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__="users"

    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password=db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username=username
        self.password=password

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<username{}'.format(self.username)
```

and my "app.py" file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, flash
from functools import wraps
#import sqlite3
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app= Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key="this is the secret key"
#app.database="users.db"

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:////users2.db'

db=SQLAlchemy(app)

from models import *

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You must be logged in to complete this action')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap


@app.route('/')
def index():
    users= db.session.query(Users).all()
    return render_template('index.html', users=users)


@app.route('/testing')
def testing():
    users= db.session.query(Users).all()
    return render_template('testquery.html', users=users)


@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error= None
    #form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
    #if request.form.validate_on_submit():
        if request.form['username'] !='admin' or request.form['password'] !='admin':
            error= 'invalid credentials'
        else:
            session ['logged_in']=True
            flash('login successful')
            return redirect(url_for('loggedin'))
    #else:
        #render_template('login.html', form=form, error=error)
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/loggedin')
@login_required
def loggedin():
    return render_template('loggedin.html')


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You have been logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('welcome'))


#def connect_db():
#   return sqlite3.connect(app.database)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The method I have been using to text is the route of "/testing", the testquery.html file is what I have been trying to test with, and have been getting the error with.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>


        <table>
        {%for user in users%}
            <tr>
                <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                <td>{{user.password}}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        {%endfor%}

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried the fix i saw in another stack question:

```
def __init__(self, username, password):
    self.username=[username]
    self.password=[password]
```

To no avail, this changed nothing. 
Anyone have any idea what I need to do to make it iterable.

Comment: Please include the **full** traceback of the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `testing`, you don't have a list of users. You have **one** user here:

```
users = db.session.query(Users).first()
```

This returns just the first user in your database. As such, you cannot loop over the user either. Rename that to `user` (dropping the `s`) and remove the loop in your template:

```
@app.route('/testing')
def testing():
    user = db.session.query(Users).first()
    return render_template('testquery.html', user=user)
```

and

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
    <td>{{user.password}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Edit made, while testing I changed a bunch of things. but I was originally using "all()"

Comment: @TheTimes: you do in the `/` route.

Comment: Ok, so I basically just did what you suggested, and got it to work. I then proceeded to change it back to what I had, and it magically worked :/ I hate when things happen like that, and im sure something changed, but it seemed like programming magic.